# Subquery using JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a query in my java program like this -

```
SELECT * FROM conversation WHERE user_id != 1 AND conversation_id IN 
( SELECT conversation_id FROM conversation WHERE user_id = 1)
```

This returns 0 rows in the result using jdbc. However if I copy and paste it into phpmyadmin it works fine. So what's going wrong?

I have added ?allowMultiQueries=true to my jdbc connection string to see if that would make a difference but it hasnt.

**Edit:**

Here is what my table looks like. I am looking to select the ids of users in conversations with user 1. Ive just noticed I left out the ! in the != in the query above, Ive put it in now. So anyone know why this works with phpmyadmin and not jdbc?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you want to do a JOIN?  That certainly works.

Comment: what does the jdbc call look like? any inputs or are the 1's part of the query in jdbc?

Comment: Your sub-query does not make any sense. It applies the same condition as the outer query but with the overhead of the extra query. You do not need to set allowMultiQueries=true for a sub-query.

Comment: I have edited my post, I had put in a = instead of a !=

Comment: I don't think allowMultiQueries is going to matter. This is a single query that happens to have a subquery -- it's not two queries. You could still do it as a join, but that doesn't answer your question -- just avoids it. That said, I don't have an answer to your question. :)

Comment: OMG, I have been trying stuff and searching for answers for an hour and Ive just noticed that I had called getResultSet() to generate the results...

Comment: "hadn't called getResultSet()"...

Answer (score -1):

Are you logged in with the identical credentials and to the same database in both JDBC and in phpmyadmin? Been there, done that - was logged into a different (and empty) db and couldn't figure out why the queries were failing.

Comment: @Carsten et al why the downvote love? If the OP is truly copy/pasting the query and there are no bugs in the Java or any SQLExceptions, the problem probably isn't in the query syntax.